# Next/image doesn't load my src image when I use a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, carousel, next-images

I use next/image to load my images in my app. It works fine except for a carousel with multiple images.
When I do like this I have that error :

Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {}

The problem is not because I have an entity without any file

image.js

```
import { getStrapiMedia } from "../utils/medias"
import NextImage from "next/image"

const Image = (props) => {
  if (!props.media) {
    return <NextImage {...props} />
  }

  const { url, alternativeText } = props.media

  const loader = ({ src }) => {
    return getStrapiMedia(src)
  }

  return (
    <NextImage
      loader={loader}
      layout="responsive"
      objectFit="contain"
      width={props.media.width}
      height={props.media.height}
      src={url}
      alt={alternativeText || ""}
    />
  )
}

export default Image
```

Carousel.js

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react"
import useEmblaCarousel from "embla-carousel-react"
import NextImage from "./Image"

export const EmblaCarousel = (product) => {
  const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel()

  useEmblaCarousel.globalOptions = { loop: true }

  const scrollPrev = useCallback(() => {
    if (emblaApi) emblaApi.scrollPrev()
  }, [emblaApi])

  const scrollNext = useCallback(() => {
    if (emblaApi) emblaApi.scrollNext()
  }, [emblaApi])

  return (
    <div className="embla" ref={emblaRef}>
      <div className="embla__container">
        {product.gallery.map((_gallery) => (
          <div key={_gallery.id}>
            <NextImage media={_gallery.image} className="embla__slide" />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button
        className="hidden md:inline embla__prev mr-2"
        onClick={scrollPrev}
      >
        Prev
      </button>
      <button
        className="hidden md:inline embla__next ml-2"
        onClick={scrollNext}
      >
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default EmblaCarousel
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is

```js
 if (!props.media) {
    return <NextImage {...props} />
  }
```

in your custom Image component. When the `media` prop is **falsy** like `undefined` or `null`, you're passing everything else to `NextImage` but that everything else doesn’t include `src` prop which is mandatory for next Image component. Also your `url` extraction is dependent on `media` prop to be **truthy** and have a property called `url`. Can be seen from the next line :-

`const { url, alternativeText } = props.media`

And you intend to pass this `url` to `src` as can be seen from your usage. Either you can return `null` when `media` is **falsy** or you can filter out those items in your list where `media` prop is **falsy** and then map on it.

Comment: I see yes. But, if I return null, I don't have the error anymore, but I still don't have the pictures

Comment: It should have the media prop actually. I don't understand why It doesn't get it

Comment: I tried to use directly the next/image without the image.js component, but it still doesn't give me anything. It got the image url because I needed to add the domain in next.config

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found an answer for this but I was running into the same issue and noticed that when looping through the multiple images object from Strapi the object is slightly different than with single images.

To fix this issue I supplied it to the `getStrapiMedia()` function in the same way it expects single images i.e:

```
{aboutpage?.attributes.shareCta.images.data.slice(0, 4).map((image) => (
<div key={image.id} className="relative h-64 w-full">
  <Image
    layout="fill"
    objectFit="cover"
    placeholder="blur"
    blurDataURL={blurDataUrl}
    src={
      getStrapiMedia({ data: image }) ||
      "/images/placeholders/image-placeholder.png"
    }
  />
</div>
  ));
}
```

Hope this helps and kind regards